# Chaining GET requests to WP REST API in Express

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore, promise, async-await

I am struggling to understand callbacks, promises, and async/await.

What I want to do is read a .csv file inside my project folder that contains 150+ post ID's.

For each one of those ID's I want to make a https GET request to fetch a JSON response from my Wordpress website.

Then for each one of those posts that gets returned I want to insert them in my Firestore database.

I'm struggling with how to properly set up the callback functions.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const https = require("https");
const Recipe = require("../includes/newrecipe");
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var serviceAccount = require("../service_key.json");
const collectionKey = "recipes"; //name of the collection
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "<MY_FIRESTORE_URL>"
});
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const fs = require('fs');
const parse = require('csv-parser');

function prepareCsvData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //establish empty csvData array and filename to be referenced
        var csvData = [];
        var filename = 'wprm_recipe_ids.csv';
        //read the csv file and push the data object into the array
        fs.createReadStream(filename)
            .pipe(parse(['ID']))
            .on('data', (data) => csvData.push(data))
            .on('end', () => { resolve(csvData); });
    });
}

function getRecipeFromBlog(recipeId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //make the get request to my website to get the recipe
        https.get('<MY_WEBSITE_URL>' + recipeId, (response) => {
            var body = "";
            response.on('data', function (chunk) { body += chunk; });
            response.on('end', () => {
                var { recipe } = JSON.parse(body);
                //build new recipe to be exported
                var newRecipe = new Recipe(recipe);
                resolve(newRecipe);
            });
        });
    });
}

/* GET recipes. */
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {

    //first prepare the csv data
    //function returns a promise with the csv data 
    //that I can then use in the next step
    const csvData = await prepareCsvData();

    for (var i = 0; csvData.length < i; i++) {
        getRecipeFromBlog(csvData[i].ID)
        .then((newRecipe) => {
            //when I have a recipe for a given recipe ID
            //update database in firestore
            firestore
                .collection(collectionKey)
                .doc(""+newRecipe.id)
                .set(newRecipe)
                .then(function() {
                    console.log('document written');
                });
        });
    }

    res.send('done');
});
```

Comment: instead of looping and inserting records one by one you can do like
push all the promises in an array ie all the get requests and use 
promise.all ( [ array of promises ] ) with the return result's you can map the data according to your need and perform bulk insertion in firestore!

Comment: @parseshyam interesting! How would I refactor the code I've written to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like below:
Play around this, You'll get it working hopefully!

Let me know if that worked!

```
      router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
      const csvData = await prepareCsvData();
      const recipePromises = [];

      // check if data is empty or not
      if (!csvData.length) {
       return res.send("Empty data");
      }
      csvData.forEach((element) => {
        recipePromises.push(getRecipeFromBlog(element.id));
      });
    
      // await for all promises parallelly.
      const result = await Promise.all(recipePromises);
    
      // Get a new write batch
      const batch = db.batch();
    
      result.forEach((recipe) => {
        const ref = db.collection("recipes").doc(`${recipe.id}`);
        batch.set(ref, recipe);
      });
    
      // Commit the batch
      await batch.commit();
      res.send("done");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was able to find a blog post that broke it down and I was able to copy the code in the blog post and apply it to my situation.

Answer (score 0):

The OP code looks pretty close to working. Have the promise-returning functions been tested? Assuming they work, first decorate them as async...

```
async function prepareCsvData() {...}
async function getRecipeFromBlog(recipeId) {...}
```

Create another promise-returning function to insert many recipes into firebase...

```
async function writeRecipesToFB(recipes) {
  const collectionRef = collection(collectionKey);
  const promises = recipes.map(recipe => {
    return collectionRef.doc(`${recipe.id}`).set(recipe);
  });
  return Promise.all(promises)
}
```

As another answer suggests, *as an alternative*, firebase's batch write is a good idea...

```
async function writeRecipesToFB(recipes) {
  // as a set of promises
  const collectionRef = collection(collectionKey);
  const batch = db.batch();
  recipes.forEach(recipe => {
    const docRef = collectionRef.doc(`${recipe.id}`)
    batch.set(docRef, recipe)
  });
  return batch.commit();
}
```

Now the express function is easy to write...

```
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  const csvData = await prepareCsvData();
  let promises = csvData.map(row => {
    return getRecipeFromBlog(row.ID);
  });
  const recipes = await Promise.all(promises);
  await writeRecipesToFB(recipes);
  res.send('done');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was able to find a blog post that broke it down and I was able to copy the code in the blog post and apply it to my situation.